# Varnish Grace Period

Tags: varnish

These are my settings for a grace period (/etc/varnish/default.vcl)

```
sub vcl_recv {
....
set req.grace = 360000s;
...
}

sub vcl_fetch {
...
set beresp.grace = 360000s; 
...
}
```

I tested Varnish using localhost and nodejs as a server. I started localhost, the site was up. Then I disconnected server and the site got disconnected in less than 2 min. It says:

Error 503 Service Unavailable
Service Unavailable
Guru Meditation:
XID: 1890127100
Varnish cache server

Could you tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that **only your cached content** will be serve in the grace delay.

Could you try to request several times the request when the backend is alive, and be sure with varnishlog for example, that as long as you're in the TTL delay no more backend connections are used.

Then, disconnect your backend, wait until you reach the content's TTL, and requery the initial request.